# React Native: Error decoding image data from CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, camera-roll

I'm getting a warning sign, saying

```
Possible: Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Error decoding image data
```

This is my code.

```
for (let media of mediaArray) {   
  await CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(
    'https://someurl.mp4',
  ); 
}
```

I was able to get this to work with a url that has a .jpg, but when I tried a .mp4 url, it doesn't work. I know the url is correct, but not sure why I'm getting this? Am I missing something if I have to save both either photo or video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that was interested in this, I found out that CameraRoll doesn't support video files that are coming from remote sources.

What I did was use `rn-fetch-blog` to save the file into the computer and then finally used CameraRoll as a supplement.

This snippet allows you to go through an array of photos and videos

```
selectedMedia.map(index => {
  let extension = cleanUrl.split('.').pop();
  RNFetchBlob.config({
    fileCache: true,
    appendExt: extension,
  })
    .fetch('GET', index.mediaUrl)
    .then(res => {
      // the temp file path
      CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(res.path());
    });
});
```